# Rules for doing operations with arguments during function execution in javascript

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, we can define a function like this:

```
function threePly(input_int)
{
    return input_int*3;
}
```

And then execute it like this:

```
threePly(12); //returns: 36
```

However, we can also do operations like this:

```
threePly(12+3) //returns: 45
```

Where can one find the rules for doing these operations with function execution arguments? How did it become known that this was possible?

Comment: Why do you think it should not be possible? You can send whatever you'd like as an argument, and it's up to the function to decide what to do with that value. Any operations are allowed.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy And where is that documented? Can you provide a source, given that JS is a language based on a specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where can one find the rules for doing these operations with function execution arguments?

Fundamentally, the answer is: In [the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/): Calling a function is primarily covered by the [EvaluateCall](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-evaluatecall) abstract operation, which does the [ArgumentListEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-argument-lists-runtime-semantics-argumentlistevaluation) abstract operation to evaluate the values for the arguments prior to making the call (*"...let ___ be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression"*). That's what tells you that the expression given as an argument is evaluated prior to being passed to the function.

But this is a fundamental thing shared with nearly all other programming languages that exist: The value of a function argument can be determined by using an expression. The links above are just the JavaScript spec way of expressing it.

The only time that's not true in any programming language with function paramters that I've ever seen is in the relatively few languages with the ability to pass variables by reference (such as `ref` or `out` parameters in C#). In those languages, you can't use an expression for the argument for a pass-by-reference parameter because it needs a variable to refer to. (You can for pass-by-value parameters in those same languages.) JavaScript is a purely pass-by-value language, though, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks. Given that there are exceptions as you have outlined, knowing why this works in JS should be documented somewhere. I knew it was possible, but I can't remember how I learned it was indeed possible, and I couldn't find it in the ES5 spec. Plus, it wasn't mentioned on MDN, or maybe I'm not looking in the right places.

Comment: @ObinwanneHill - The JavaScript spec can be difficult to read. :-) I've updated the answer to call out a couple of sections.

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks. Difficult to read might be understating things. It might make sense to define a *PlainSpecs* standard for the creation of specification documents a 12-year old can read. Until then, empiricism is bound to reign.

Comment: @ObinwanneHill - Well, I don't agree about empiricism, but that doesn't matter. :-) You may also find this useful: [*How to Read the ECMAScript Specification*](https://timothygu.me/es-howto/)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you put inside the parenthases is evaluated before it's passed to the function. You can even layer them as many times as you want.

`var x = logE(double(triple(quarter(12))));` -- it will run `quarter(12);` first, and then pass that result to the `triple` function, and whatever that returns will get passed to `double`, and what that returns will get passed to `logE`, and what that returns will get assigned to `x`;

If it wasn't designed this way, it would be very tedious to do a lot of pretty basic things.

Comment: Thanks. But where did you learn that this could be done? Where is it stated? I'm looking for a source for this functionality.

Comment: I... don't know. I probably read a basic programming book back when I was learning Python, and just assumed the same concepts applied to javascript, because function-calling looks similar in javascript -- and it turned out my assumption was right.

Comment: Ok. As T.J. Crowder pointed out above, that functionality does not apply everywhere. So I just wanted to track down something in spec that identifies that such a thing is possible.